# How can I add a keyboard shortcut for Find-In-Files in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-management-studio

I'd like to make it Ctrl-Shift-F to match Visual Studio.

I realize to do that I need to remove that binding from the Query->Save to File item.

But, I can't even add ANY shortcut.  When I pull up the Tools/Customize box, pick Edit in the Categories and then Find-in-Files in the Commands, the box for "Modify Selection", where I assume I could add a shortcut, is greyed out.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is very powerful.  I don't know the exact menu structure for SQL Server Management Studio, so I can't mock up a script for you, but they are easy to write.  Regardless of this particular question, I firmly believe AutoHotkey should be in every SuperUser's toolkit. :)

Comment: Heh..... I use autohotkey, but for playing online poker!

Comment: Haha, too funny.  Well now you potentially have a new use for it!

Comment: I don't think you can change the keyboard shortcuts in SQL Server Management Studio. It's limited to defining shortcut keys for stored procedures like `sp_who` and `sp_helptext`-- useful though that is, it's not much help to you! I think you'll have to use a third-party utility like AutoHotkey or similar to do what you want.